# How to hold every view in one?

Tags: android, android-layout, surfaceholder

I need to transport every view in my layout somewhere else in that layout... So i need something to put every view in it, and move only it... How can i manage this? (It may be too easy, sorry if it is, but i'm pretty new on android. I've heard something like "holder" but i'm not so sure if it can be move with

```
setMarginLeft(...)
```

Thanks in advance for helps!

Put every view in one another RelativeLayout, but now i cannot see the views?

**xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/menu"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/leftLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/leftMenu"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Left Menu"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="344dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp" >

    </ListView>


</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: use another layout as holder and move whole layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a single a parent view, take a linearlayout or other layout:

and set margin to that layout.

Comment: I did, but now i cannot see my other elements... Could u check my question updated with xml file?

Comment: remove these lines: android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"